# Why does the addBBands() function error when the chartSeries plots using the same dataset?

Tags: r

After retrieving OHLC data using the getSymbols function, I'm adding a column to the OHLC data.  I can plot the chart using the chartSeries function, but when I try to add Bollinger Bands using the addBBands() function, I get an error.

When removing the extra column from the OHLC data, the addBBands() function works fine.  It's not clear to me if it's supposed to work this way or if this is a design shortcoming.

```
library (quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL")
AAPL <- cbind(AAPL,AAPL[,4])
chartSeries(AAPL["2018"])
addBBands()
```

The chart plots and I would expect the addBBands() function to plot the Bollinger Bands, but I get the error, "Price series must be either High-Low-Close, or Close/univariate."

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. `BBands` checks the names of the columns. The check is based on the columns names. In your example you have 2 columns which contain the word **Close**. This is where it goes wrong. If you name the new column anything except high, low, open, close, volume it will work. Something like below.

```
library (quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL")
AAPL <- cbind(AAPL,AAPL[,4])

# rename last column so it doesn't have "close" in the column name 
names(AAPL)[7] <- "AAPL.New.Col"

chartSeries(AAPL["2018"])
addBBands()
```

Comment: I did rename the last column as you suggested and continue to get the error.

Comment: check the result of names(AAPL) and see what that returns. It should work on the example. But only in a clean R environment.

Comment: Here's the names result.  I also wiped the environment before running it and continue to get the same error.
AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted AAPL.New.Col

Comment: Should work fine. I don't have any issues with this. Have you restarted your R session?

Comment: Same issue after restarting R session.  I'm using RStudio Version 1.1.463. My quantmod package revision is 0.4-12.  Is yours the same?

Comment: R 3.5, quantmod 0.4-13.1, TTR 0.23-4

Comment: I'm running RStudio on a Mac.  Just updated R to 3.5.2 and updated quantmod package to 0.4-13 and TTR to 0.23-4.  Still getting same error.  I wonder if it occurs only on the Mac platform.

Comment: Finally got it... the column name change needs to go before chartSeries().  Thank you for your help.